Data visualisation: datavisualisation library or pgfplots
I am trying to migrate by lab data visualistion routine from matplotlib to latex. I came a cross some libraries, including the package pgfplots and the tikz's datavisualisation libarary. I am not sure which one is better for plotting large data sets from experiments. I think pgfplots is the more developed one and datavisualistion library is rather new?
Its been almost five years since this review, is there any update about their functions and popularities?

Welcome. // Kindly see my answer below ... which probaly doesn't qualify a solution ...

Some answers to your question.
Popularity
Following both tags:

pgfplots: 9,764 questions
datavisualization: 111 questions

In a nutshell ...
Though you can do many things with pgfplots I perceive its main advantage in creating data plots like you'd publish in scientific journals.
In this view pgfplots is quite versatile, many things are prepared, and many more can be unlocked if you are willing to spend time and energy. But it's tricky every now and then.
datavizualization is less staffed, but by writing your own data handler you can do many things, sometimes easier than with pgfplots.
E.g. this example using school book axes was almost a no-brainer with datavisualization, while pgfplots doesn't have something similar ready to use, AFIK.
You may want to check some of my answers on the required data handler here. (Though there are certainly more experienced veterans here on this subject ...)
Suggestion
Try identifying a small set of very different drawings you already have and try to get an idea, what it means to replicate them with pgfplots or datavisualization.
Alternatives
Unless you know it already have a look into the guide of the graphicx package, which may allow you to re-use your existing drawings, e.g. from bitmap (.png etc.) or vector (non-bitmapped .pdf). You could even use .svg with other packages.
